# How to make privileged system app without using android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing a system app and the attribute `'android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"'` is declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml.`

However, the item `android:sharedUserId` is deprecated in `API 29`, so it seems not to be recommended to use `android:sharedUserId` anymore.
Then, is there any other way to develop privileged system app in the android studio, without using the attribute `android:sharedUserId`?  Is it possible to develop and execute the privileged app just using the platform keys?

Answer (score 0):

Use AIDL (Android Interface Definition Language): AIDL allows communication between apps via inter-process communication (IPC). System apps can expose AIDL interfaces that can be accessed by other system apps. This can help in building modular and secure system apps.

Content Providers: You can use content providers to expose data and functionality securely to other system apps. By defining well-defined APIs and permissions, you can ensure controlled access.

System Signature: If your app is part of the system image and signed with the system signature, it gets additional privileges without needing to share a user ID. This approach allows you to access certain system-level permissions.

Permission Management: Define your app's custom permissions using the  tag in the manifest. Other apps that need to interact with your app can request and use these permissions.

App-to-App Communication: Use standard Android communication mechanisms like broadcasts, services, and intents to allow your system app to communicate with other system apps or apps with the proper permissions.

Platform Keys: If you are developing and building the entire Android system, you could consider using platform keys to sign your app. This would grant it system-level privileges. However, using platform keys requires deep integration into the Android platform and build process.